# How to solve the login error in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made a login page in php. for database i have used here mysql. If i want to login it is always showing the message username password wrong ...but there is already exist the username and password. So i cannot find out what is the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sazal/my4wvnvt/

this is my login design page..

here is below the checklogin.php code..

```
// userName and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['pwd'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userName='$myusername' and pass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1 ){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
//session_register("myusername");
//$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername; // Initializing Session
//$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
//$_SESSION['password']=$mypassword;
//session_register("mypassword");
header("location:home.php");
}
else {
//echo "Wrong Username or Password";
header("Location:index.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Wrong Username or Password"));
}
?>
```

Comment: You should be using mysqli PDO.  You also aren't hashing your passwords.  Try checking if `$count > 0`.

Comment: storing passwords in plain text is evil!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your form elements have no name attributes. You cannot rely on an "id" alone.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
```

and

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
```

You need to add them, since you are declaring

```
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['pwd'];
```

Modify to:

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
```

and

```
<input name="pwd" type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
```

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

Sidenote: You should also add `exit;` after each header.

I.e.:

```
if($count==1 ){
    header("location:home.php");
    exit;
}
else {
//echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    header("Location:index.php?errorMssg=".urlencode("Wrong Username or Password"));
    exit;
}
```

---

- Consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

A few things to also consider is that your column(s) length should be long enough to accomodate your data as is the column type.

When storing password hashes, I myself use `VARCHAR` to its fullest; 255.

I admit it's an overkill, *but that's just me.*

Comment: Nice for the comment on password hashing. It's advisable to never send the password plain over the line. You can find JavaScript `sha1` hash functions on Google.

Comment: @Mouser It should be sent over HTTPS from client to server to be processed in PHP. Using SHA1 would make it impossible to later use CRYPT_BLOWFISH, which is a _good_ hashing algorithm. SHA1 itself is no longer considered suitable or secure enough for password storage.

Comment: @Mouser - As per Michael's comment. Michael basically took the words right out of my mouth lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's weird. The first PHP book I read in 2003 explained the explicit `exit()` after Location headers, but I see soooooo much code where it isn't used. At my job, I debugged a legacy script that had been double-logging events for _years_ due to that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I too was victim of that "once". I always add it in any instance of a header.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski true, but HTTPS requires a certificate which isn't exactly always cheap. What would you advise for beginning website builder or non-commercial ones.

Comment: @Mouser - There is no alternative way to transport a password safely to the server, but HTTPS. However you try to encrypt the password at client side, a ManInTheMiddle can do exactly the same. There are providers which offer HTTPS for free using their own domain, example: https://yourdomain.providerdomain.com

Comment: @SazalAhmed It's posted above. Immediately after `header("Location...");` always call `exit;`. If you do not, PHP will continue to execute code even after the client has been redirected away.

Comment: @Mouser There are also SSL providers who offer free cert registrations to non-profits or for non-commercial use http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/any-non-commercial-certificate-authority-issuer-for-web-applications

Comment: @MatinStoeckli and Michael. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @SazalAhmed As Michael mentioned earlier, I have added it in my answer. Reload it to see it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and Michael...Thanks you both for your answer...i have got it

Comment: @SazalAhmed You're very much welcome Sazal, *cheers*. Thanks to all for their contribution with their comments also. This was a good discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input name="username"...>
```

Not:

```
<input id="username"...>
```

Same for password.

It's the value of the "name" attribute that indexes the `$_POST` array.

Also, try a `var_dump($_POST);` in your php script, to test what you actually receive from your html form, before searching errors on the mysql side.

Answer (score 0):

Your input fields has no name attributes use name="" 
using id's and class's does not sent the values of the filed via post request
without name attribute the input field you can't get data via post request